# Best method to save & retrieve images to database

Tags: android, image, sqlite

Looking for advice on above.
Looking to create a SQLlite DB where each row of data is mainly strings but I also want to save an image taken from the phone.

Is it advisable or possible to save the encoded base 64 string of a bitmap image and convert it back to image when the row of data is called?

I also read somewhere that there is a blob column type that can save image binary data.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to do, but you could also use Blobs as well (see this post [How to store and retrieve a byte array (image data) to and from a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191136/how-to-store-and-retrieve-a-byte-array-image-data-to-and-from-a-sqlite-databas)).  If you want to store the images as Base64 strings, though, it's pretty easy to do, just use the Apache library to encode the raw image `bytes[]` to a `Base64 String`.

Here's the reference:  [Apache Base 64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29)

First you'll want to encode the image `bytes[]` using `public static String encodeBase64String(byte[] binaryData)`.

Then, you can store the `Base64` String in your database.

When you go to retrieve the image, just use `public static byte[] decodeBase64(String base64Data)`
to convert the `String` back to `bytes[]`, and use the `BitmapFactory` to get the `Bitmap`.

Edit:

Played around with this for a bit, and for some reason after adding the core `commons-codec-1.9.jar`, I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.  In case this problem isn't specific to my build, it's the same as:

```
String base64string = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(drawable), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: So does the base64 string occupy less space than its image equivalent?

Comment: Nah, in most cases (making room for edge cases I don't know about...), storing the raw data will be smaller.  Still, knowing how to store and convert to/from Base64 strings can be useful in other situations - or also in the situation where you can't change you DB scheme.