# Image to text android app

Tags: java, android, api

Trying to use TextFairy code on GitHub to create an android app which converts image to text as one of its features:  (https://github.com/renard314/textfairy/tree/master/app/src/main/res), but it is throwing this error:
Please help!
or suggest some other image to text api/android app code

```
 Executing tasks:      [:app:generateAV5DebugSources,:app:generateAV5DebugAndroidTestSources, :tesstwo:tess-two:generateDebugSources, :tess-two:tesstwo:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Returning version 640
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 240
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 140
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
signing.properties not found
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkAV5DebugManifest
:app:preAV5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/renard/devel/android-ndk-r9c//ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.02 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleAV5Debug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Returning version 640
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 240
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 140
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
signing.properties not found
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkAV5DebugManifest
:app:preAV5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/renard/devel/android-ndk-r9c//ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.917 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleAV5Debug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Returning version 640
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 240
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 140
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
signing.properties not found
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkAV5DebugManifest
:app:preAV5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/renard/devel/android-ndk-r9c//ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.946 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleAV5Debug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Returning version 640
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 240
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 140
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
signing.properties not found
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkAV5DebugManifest
:app:preAV5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/renard/devel/android-ndk-r9c//ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.68 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleAV5Debug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Returning version 640
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 240
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Returning version 140
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
signing.properties not found
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkAV5DebugManifest
:app:preAV5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preAV7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/renard/devel/android-ndk-r9c//ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.703 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
    Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
    byte[] ba;
    do {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Log.e("BEFORE REDUCING",
                bitmap.getHeight() + " " + bitmap.getWidth() + " "
                        + bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        ba = bao.toByteArray();
        if ((ba.length / 1024) >= 650) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                    (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * 0.95),
                    (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * 0.95), true);

        }

        Log.e("BYTE LENGTH", "" + ba.length / 1024);

    } while ((ba.length / 1024) >= 650);

    String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

this code converts images to 64 bit string. For more follow this link [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

[1](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/util/Base64.html): [how to convert an image into base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297381/how-to-convert-an-image-into-base64-string) and [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Comment: how would i incorporate that into an app

Comment: if you want to store in database follow this  link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048506/best-method-to-save-retrieve-images-to-database    if you want to store on server, just use  ("key",base^4Image) in json format.