# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted] while reading data from Sqlite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have successfully saved my data in SQLite DB. But I am getting an error while reading data from my SQLite DB and then my app is crashing.

> error message

```
01-01 05:42:13.916 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=607 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=68313184
01-01 05:42:13.916 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=607 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=68313184
01-01 05:42:13.916 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2910 stm=2910 core=0
01-01 05:42:13.916 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2910 stm=2910 core=0
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at com.example.eyesaver.SQ_Lite_DB.ReadSqliteData(SQ_Lite_DB.java:59)
01-01 05:42:13.917 607-607/com.example.eyesaver I/dalvikvm:     at com.example.eyesaver.SQ_Lite_DB.ReadSqliteData(SQ_Lite_DB.java:59)// I marked this line in code
```

and

```
1-01 05:42:16.189 607-607/com.example.eyesaver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.eyesaver, PID: 607
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 05:42:16.189 607-607/com.example.eyesaver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.eyesaver, PID: 607
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am reading data from my SQLite using the 'ReadSqliteData()' method

> ReadSqliteData() method

```
public void ReadSqliteData(Context context){
    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Adpter adpter = new Adpter(list,context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));   //i am getting error here 
            model.setName(cursor.getString(1));    //i am getting error here 
            list.add(model);
        }
        adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
}
```

And one more problem: my id is null in the SQLite database, I don't know why? I am creating a table like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                "Create Table orders"+
                        "(id INTERGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                        "image text ,"+
                        "name text)"
        );
    }
```

If you need any other information let me know.

Comment: Please don't suggest enabling a big heap because my application is too small?

Comment: ˋINTERGERˋ in your create statement should probably be INTEGER…?

Comment: @forpas sorry, I used your code to solve it. Now I have accepted your answer. But even that answer is not waste. check my edit. why the data is not saving in my model class.

Comment: @SachinBurdak if you have a new problem you should ask a new question and explain there what the problem is. By editing your current question with a new requirement you invalidate the answers that you already got.

Comment: @forpas  done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68055617/data-loaded-from-sqlite-databse-is-not-saving-in-the-model-class-arraylist-andro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop never ends because in each iteration you set the cursor's index at the 1st row with `moveToFirst()` without advancing to the next row.
Use `moveToNext()` only:

```
public void ReadSqliteData(Context context){
    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Adpter adpter = new Adpter(list,context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));            
        model.setName(cursor.getString(1));    
        list.add(model);
    }
    adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code.

```
//update your table create query, id should be auto increment and also your query was not in correct form.

 db.execSQL(
            "Create Table orders"+
                    "("+ id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                    "image text ,"+
                    "name text" +")"
    );


//update you read method code
 public void ReadSqliteData(Context context){
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
Adpter adpter = new Adpter(list,context);
SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
if (cursor.moveToNext()){
    while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));   
        model.setName(cursor.getString(1));   
        list.add(model);

    }
    adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
cursor.close();
database.close();
}
```

Comment: while (cursor.moveToFirst()) is not correct replace this with while (cursor.moveToNext())