# data loaded from SQLitE databse is not saving in the model class ArrayList android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, pojo

I am retrieving data from my `SQLite database`. I checked that my data is retrieving successfully but this is not saving in the ArrayList of my `Model Class` by logging values.

and then I logged the value of `list. size()` of my  `getItemCount()` method of my `Adpter` which is 0. so why my data is not saving in the model class.

> ReadSqliteData() method

```
public void ReadSqliteData(Context context){
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
Adpter adpter = new Adpter(list,context);
SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    Model model = new Model();
    model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));            
    model.setName(cursor.getString(1));    
    list.add(model);
}
adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
cursor.close();
database.close();
}
```

and this method in my adapter class

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("tag",String.valueOf(list.size())); /// i am getting this value 0
        return list.size();
    }
```

I tried putting constructor also. but that is also not working.

> Model.java

[image: Model.java class]

if Adapter code needed comment below

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code.

```
 class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adatper<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>(){
 //add new method in adapter class
 Public void dataChange(ArrayList<Model> itemList){
  //update your previous list with the new list
  previousList = itemList;
  notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

}


public void ReadSqliteData(Context context){
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
Adpter adpter = new Adpter(list,context);
SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
Model model = new Model();
model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));            
model.setName(cursor.getString(1));    
list.add(model);
}
//call adapter dataChange() method from here
adpter.dataChange(list);
cursor.close();
database.close();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that approach. I always used that approach when using Firebase before.

Comment: your adapter not getting latest item list on calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I was creating a new 'ArrayList' and 'Adapter' in this method. Whereas I have to pass these to my activity where I am setting `layoutmanager` and `adapter` to `recyclerview`. Then that approach would be correct. Please check and upvote my answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055662/15622565

Comment: still your problem not resolved of notifying recyclerview with updated data?

Comment: your approach is not correct because every time you will create a new adapter instance on data change, you should use same instance every iteration

Comment: Your concept of the answer is good too. But when I pass `ArrayList and `Adapter` as parameters. Thank you. you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the adapter class, create public function to set the new items by

```
// Adapter Class
public void setItems(List<Model> newItems) {
    this.list = newItems;      <-- Here you need to replace with new items
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getItemsCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

From your activity `adapter.setItems(newItems);`

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because I am using different Variables for `ArrayList`and `Adpter`.
simply passing `ArrayList`and `Adpter` as a parameter to `ReadSqliteData()` Method which is used to set `LayoutManager` and `Adpter` to the `RecyclerView` the problem will be solved.,

> ReadSqliteData(Context context, ArrayList list,Adpter adpter){
> //code here
> }

```
public void ReadSqliteData(Context context, ArrayList<Model> list,Adpter adpter){
SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select name, image from orders",null);
Model model = new Model();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
model.setImage(cursor.getString(0));            
model.setName(cursor.getString(1));    
list.add(model);
}
adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
cursor.close();
database.close();
}
```

Note:- Only the `list and adapter that I am passing as parameters are used to set layout manager and Adapter to recycler view in my Activity class